# Cannot find chmod[metasploit installation]

Tags: linux, installation, chmod, metasploit

in the picture below you can see that it says chmod command is not found yet it has chmod installed. I am installing metasploit directly from the terminal(I did not install any desktop environment and don't want to run msf from there). Is there any way to solve this? I would gladly appreciate any replies.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that command, use this instead

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && chmod 755 msfinstall && ./msfinstall`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslashes from the composite Bash command, they're used in Linux to escape the space character. For example, ỳou would have to type:

```
cd ~/Documents/My\ Folder
```

to access

```
~/Documents/My Folder
```

By writing the command the way you did you were looking for the ' chmod'  command instead of 'chmod', you've basically inserted a space before the command name. 
I'd suggest studying Linux Bash scripting before venturing into Metasploit.
You would otherwise continually stumble against this kind of issues, also if you'd like to work with Metasploit from its command console it's pretty much mandatory to study Linux Bash scripting (and the Linux OS as a whole).